# How to change background colour in List view if the item in list view is unselected

Tags: android, xml, android-layout

I am working in android to develop an app which contains a list view in which the background colour of the particular item is changed when the item is clicked ( which is already performed using "ListSelector" in .xml file). Now I need to deselect the item which I done through " mListview.clearChoices()". But background colour of the previously selected item is not changed.
Can you guys give some solution ?

Here is my xml code:

```
<ListView
          android:id="@+id/listView"
          android:layout_width="@dimen/dp_130"
          android:layout_height="wrap_content"
          android:background="@color/malibu"
          android:gravity="center"
          android:minHeight="@dimen/dp_50"
          android:listSelector="#e60b62da"/>
```

Here is the code in Activity file:

```
mListView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                check = 1;
                item_position=position;
                Toast.makeText(MacroActivity.this, "Item clicked_ macro" + position, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                item_value = (String) mListView.getItemAtPosition(position);
                Toast.makeText(MacroActivity.this, "Item clicked_ macro_value" + item_value, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    mListView.clearChoices();
            }
        });
```

Comment: You can pass a boolean flag to the list item you select and after that you can use notifydatasetchange(); to triiger the adapter where you can choose what to do with current list items which you have selected, Note that you also have to pass the boolean flag when declaring you adapter.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you select a list item view (into `onItemClick` method) you can set a variable in your adapter to keep selected list item index. Then you can call `notifyDatasetChange()`. In your adapter where you create and set your list item views properties you can check if selected index correspond with current selected view. In that case you can set a colour, otherwise you can set another one.

Hope that helps

Answer (score 0):

This is one of the feasible solution which can be used to solve the above question. I used the listview.setSelector() in which the background colour assigned for the item in the listview can be nullified, yet this function does not allow to set background colour for another item in the listview if needed so.

> mListView.setSelector(new ColorDrawable(0));